# How can I enable reminders in react-native using firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a task management app, and I want to send local notifications when the task is due, 3 hours before the task and two days before the task.
When the task is created, all the data and deadline are saved in a cloud firestore document. How can I write the code such that when the reminderTime === deadline (in firestore document), a notification gets sent.

And also I want to prevent users from changing their system time to extend the deadline, I believe I can do this using cloud functions, I will verify the deadline using a cloud function and send a notification when it's actually that time, I think this will bypass the system time and send a notification.

Can someone explain how can I write this code?